# lottie animation is playing too fast

Tags: lottie

I added demo animation to the web using lottie, but the playback speed is too fast. How do I get to normal speed? The link below is a problem animation.

problem animation link : https://saybgm.github.io/Lottie_example/

My animation : https://youtu.be/CcHT7VgUF38

After Effect aep file : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YGqgiuU-hU5Raq2WXu3r1ZrCANXB_Gw9/view?usp=sharing

my code

```js
var animate = lottie.loadAnimation({
container: document.getElementById("hello"),
renderer: 'svg',
autoplay: true,
loop:true,
path: 'animation2.json'})
```

Comment: Post your current code so everyone can help

Comment: https://github.com/SayBGM/Lottie_example
This is github link.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think the problem is inside the animation file, tried with the Lottiefiles preview, it looks the same as your code runs: https://www.lottiefiles.com/share/TNdLkQ

If you want to make it slower, call `setSpeed` (1 is the current speed, < 1 will make it slower):

```js
var animate = lottie.loadAnimation({
  container: document.getElementById("hello"),
  renderer: 'svg',
  autoplay: true,
  loop:true,
  path: 'animation2.json'
});
animate.setSpeed(0.1);
```

From the document: http://airbnb.io/lottie/web/getting-started.html

Answer (score 13):

Also you can handle it on XML file. Go to the Lottie tag, then implement

```
app:lottie_speed="any number"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also set the speed directly on the component if you are using react

```js
<LottieView
  speed={0.2}
  ref={animation}
  loop={true}
  autoPlay={true}
  ...
/>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are following the new way of implementing Lottie in React you can use it like this(similar to Michael's answer who got my upvote):

```html
<Lottie
    options={defaultOptions}
    height={'100%'}
    width={'100%'}
    isStopped={false}
    isPaused={false}
    speed={0.25}
/>
```